# Is there a name for this constant and its value where $\alpha = \sum_{p}\frac{\log \left({p}\right)}{p \left({p-1}\right)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, constants

The constant $$\alpha = \sum_{p} \frac{\log \left({p}\right)}{p \left({p-1}\right)}$$ comes from the calculation $$\sum_{p=2}^{x} \frac{\log \left({p}\right)}{p-1} = \sum_{p=2}^{x} \frac{\log \left({p}\right)}{p} + \alpha$$

Where $p$ is a prime.  Using the primes up to ${10}^{9}$ results in $\alpha = 0.75536660\cdots$.  Does this constant have a name and is it listed with additional decimal digits of value.

The only reference to date where the constant is computed is *Explicit estimates for the Artin L-functions: Duke's short-sum theorem and Dedekind zeta residues*, by Stephan Ramon Garcia and Ethan Simpson Lee at arXiv:2101.11853v5 section 2.5

Using the results below where $\alpha$ is summed over Mobius and zeta function results in a faster convergence where we can write out to 30 decimal digits $$\alpha =
0.755366610831688021159316685989\, \cdots$$

Comment: May be this is your first time using internet. Let me tell you that writing in ALLCAPS is the equivalent of yelling. Please, don't yell at us.

Comment: @jjagmath I'm sure that's the formatting of the article title. It's very common for article titles to be typeset all in capitals, and while it's nice if a poster rewrites it or changes the formatting to something less abrasive, it's not as if they're putting on emphasis themselves.

Comment: Yes the title was all caps, I will change that.

Comment: You can find additional information on this constant in [OEIS A138312](https://oeis.org/A138312).

Comment: That was part of the answer that I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Incomplete answer)

Define the [Prime Zeta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function) $P(s)=\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^s}$. This converges uniformly for $\Re(s)>1$. Taking the derivative, $$P'(s)=-\sum_p\frac{\log p}{p^s}.$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
\alpha&=\sum_p\frac{\log p}{p(p-1)}\\
&=\sum_p\frac{\log p}{p}\frac{1/p}{1-1/p}\\
&=\sum_p\frac{\log p}{p}\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{p^n}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}\sum_p\frac{\log p}{p^{n+1}}\\
&=-\sum_{n\ge1}P'(n+1)\\
&=-\sum_{n\ge2}P'(n).
\end{align}$$
Now, recall the Euler product for $\zeta(s)$:
$$\zeta(s)=\prod_{p}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}.$$
Taking the logarithm,
$$\begin{align}
\log\zeta(s)&=-\sum_p\log(1-p^{-s})\\
&=\sum_p\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{p^{-ns}}{n}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n}\sum_p\frac{1}{p^{ns}}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{P(ns)}{n},
\end{align}$$
This can be re-written as
$$-\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{P(ns)}{n}=P(s)-\log\zeta(s).$$
Upon differentiating,
$$-\sum_{n\ge2}P'(ns)=P'(s)-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)},$$
thus
$$\alpha=-\sum_{n\ge2}P'(n)=\lim_{s\to 1^{+}}\left(P'(s)-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\right).$$
Now, via Mobius inversion,
$$\log\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{P(ns)}{n}\iff P(s)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\log\zeta(ns).$$
Differentiating $P(s)$,
$$P'(s)=\sum_{n\ge1}\mu(n)\frac{\zeta'(ns)}{\zeta(ns)}=\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}+\sum_{n\ge2}\mu(n)\frac{\zeta'(ns)}{\zeta(ns)}.$$
So,
$$\alpha=\lim_{s\to 1^{+}}\left(P'(s)-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\right)=\lim_{s\to 1^{+}}\sum_{n\ge2}\mu(n)\frac{\zeta'(ns)}{\zeta(ns)}=\sum_{n\ge2}\mu(n)\frac{\zeta'(n)}{\zeta(n)}.$$
As far as I know there is no known closed form for this.